# Python Bokeh Logger

Tags: logging, bokeh

How do you access the python Bokeh logger?

I tried using the [`basicConfig`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/util.html#bokeh-util-logconfig) wrapper but it does not seem to work.

```
from bokeh.util import logconfig
logconfig.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename="output.log")
```

Anyone had luck redirecting the server logs to a file?

I also tried creating another standard logger without using Bokeh (e.g. with `logging` module), but it does not work either.

Using Bokeh 0.12.6 (latest)

Comment: I would actually expect that to work, so I'd suggest a GitHub issue with details and complete information: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: There is now a request for this: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6699

Answer (score 4):

This was resolved in [`7755`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/7755) which added a `--log-file` command line option to `bokeh serve`. You will need to update to version `0.12.16` or later.